# Pluck hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there pluck for a hash?

I have a hash like below and I tried to pluck with following command. I know that it can be done in different ways. But I dunno if there's a pluck method with the following.

```
hash = {"0"=>{"user_id"=>"1"}, "0"=>{"user_id"=>"2"}}
hash.pluck("user_id")
```

Comment: Is it rails 3 or rails 4?

Comment: man, someone is on a downvote spree this morning :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best you can do is a simple `map`.

```
hash = {"0"=>{"user_id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"user_id"=>"2"}}
hash.values.map{|h| h['user_id']} # => ["1", "2"]
```

If you want, you can even take this and add it to `Array` as your `pluck` method. Of course, "you can" doesn't mean "you should" :)

Answer (score 2):

ActiveSupport adds [`pluck` to Enumerable](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-pluck)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
hash.inject([]) do |acc, el| 
  acc << el.last.try(:[], 'user_id').to_i
  acc
end
```

Here is the result

```
[38] pry(main)> hash.inject([]){|acc, el| acc << el.last.try(:[], 'user_id').to_i; acc}
=> [1, 2]
```

But it will work only for hash that you provided.

Or you can monkey patch Hash class with:

```
# config/initializers/hash.rb
class Hash
  def hash_pluck(key)
    self.inject([]){|acc, el| acc << el.last.try(:[], key).to_i; acc}
  end
end
```

And then call it on hash

```
[2] pry(main)> hash.hash_pluck('user_id')
=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: what's up with the `try`?

Comment: yes, I know that is a rails method not ruby. So according to tags we talking about ror.

Comment: I meant that you don't need it.

Comment: Yes, it's a habbit :) Anyways your approach even better.